# How to approach writing of custom decoding function from `ByteString` to `Text`

Tags: haskell, text, encoding, bytestring

Suppose I wish to write something like this:

```
-- | Decode a 'ByteString' containing Code Page 437 encoded text.

decodeCP437 :: ByteString -> Text
decodeCP437 = undefined
```

(I know about `encoding` package, but its dependency list is ridiculous price to pay for this single, and I believe quite trivial function.)

My question is how to construct `Text` from `ByteString` with reasonable efficiency, in particular without using lists. It seems to me that `Data.Text.Encoding` should be a good source for inspiration, but at first sight it uses `withForeignPtr` and I guess it's too low level for my use case.

How the problem should be approached? In a nutshell, I guess I need to continuously take bytes (`Word8`) from `ByteString`, translate every byte to corresponding `Char`, and somehow efficiently build `Text` from them. Complexity of [basic building functions](http://haddock.stackage.org/lts-5.4/text-1.2.2.0/Data-Text.html#g:6) in `Data.Text` for `Text` construction not surprisingly indicates that appending characters one by one is not the best idea, but I don't see better tools for this available.

---

Update: I want to create strict `Text`. It seems that the only option is to create builder then get lazy `Text` from it (O(n)) and then convert to strict `Text` (O(n)).

Comment: What about the text [`Builder`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.2.0/docs/Data-Text-Lazy-Builder.html)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [Builder](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.2.0/docs/Data-Text-Lazy-Builder.html) API, which offers O(1) `singleton :: Char -> Builder` and O(1) `(<>) :: Builder -> Builder -> Builder` for efficient construction operations.

Comment: What if I want to construct strict `Text`?

Comment: @Mark http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.2.0/docs/Data-Text-Lazy.html#toStrict

Comment: Yes I know about `toStrict`, but that's another pass over entire data. Looks like this is the only option, though. Thanks.